# Does Docker still have bootfs?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm currently looking at how Docker works. As far as I did know Docker does not boot, it just starts a process in a very chrooted environment. But when I look in some documentation some mention that Docker has a bootfs. It's a filesystem that only mounts at boot and unmounts just after rootfs is mounted (I guess). But you can't see or touch it. I even can't find it.

Is it still true that Docker uses some kind of bootfs? For example, these articles confuse me: http://collabnix.com/understanding-docker-container-image/. It has bootfs with kernel and cgroup in it. But as far as I know, the kernel is outside of Docker, that is part of the host system.

My main question is, is it still true that Docker uses bootfs to 'start' a container? And, where can I see that filesystem?

Answer (score 6):

I think you may have discovered a bit of misleading folklore. I did a Google site-search for "bootfs" (i.e. [site:docker.com bootfs](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocker.com+bootfs)) and found almost nothing - literally four results. I searched through each of these four results and I will describe what I found.

- [Docker v1.9 Documentation: Images and Containers](https://docs.docker.com/v1.9/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/)

This describes the structure of images and containers and their relation to storage drivers. The string "bootfs" does not appear on this page. Neither does the string "boot" for that matter.

- [Docker White Paper: Introduction to Container Security](https://www.docker.com/sites/default/files/WP_Intro%20to%20container%20security_03.20.2015%20%281%29.pdf)

This document describes the Docker container implementation from a security perspective. The string "bootfs" appears only once - in a diagram in which it appears to refer to the boot file-system of the host machine.

- [Docker Forums: Linux distro compatibility between host and container](https://forums.docker.com/t/linux-distro-compatibility-between-host-and-container/268)

In this forum discussion the string "bootfs" appears exactly once - again in reference to the host machine, not to a container.

- [Docker Qemu builds](https://hub.docker.com/r/pandrew/qemu/builds/btkxfvkzytmvjjwxgkwuzt/)

Here the string appears as a substring in various package names. There's no indication that it relates to starting a Docker container.

I also searched the [Docker CE GitHub](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce) but didn't find any instance of the string "bootfs".

After many Google searches of the form ["docker bootfs location"](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+bootfs+location) and ["where is docker bootfs"](https://www.google.com/search?q=where+is+docker+bootfs) I found several results which seemed to indicate that the idea of a Docker bootfs existing at the container level is a misnomer. Here are a couple such results:

- [Padge Blog: Containers Don't Really Boot](https://padgeblog.com/tag/bootfs/)

This blog post describes the Docker start-up process in some detail and distinguishes it from a typical boot process.

- [Moby Github Issue: how i upgrade bootfs](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10062)

In this issue discussion a contributor refers to bootfs as a "concept" that "you can't touch".

Answer (score 1):

I keep this record of my investigations for people that aren't satisfied by the other answers and used to trust in books. Today I believe, that bootfs is a myth or at least misleading and misunderstood.

I read about bootfs at a book from our libraries university from 2019. I contacted the lector of it and he contactet the authors and it turned out, that they had their informations from the internet, including stackoverflow. Unfortunately I had to rethink my trust in books.

I spent some hours searching google and scholar.google for what exactly bootfs actually is, but I hardly could find any information. Most of the sources that seemed at least a little useful to me mentioned it together with docker.

In the whitepaper posted by igal from docker one can clearly see bootfs as the bottom layer.
https://www.docker.com/sites/default/files/WP_Intro%20to%20container%20security_03.20.2015%20%281%29.pdf
Now as you can read in the docker docs, the **images are stored into the hosts file system** and docker utilizes them by only creating a copy-on-write-layer for each container. **I guess bootfs simply means the host system you started with**.

Unforunately there are some people quite convinced writing about bootfs, but not referencing any sources. So you can read things like bootfs would be a layer that is created for each image, etc. etc.

Comment: You appear to have parroted the misconception that the existing answerers worked hard to try to correct.

Comment: I deleted my (early) answer now. As you say, it was simply an assertion. The answer with the sources (and upvotes) is strictly better :-). The reason I find an answer based on searching so credible, is that Docker is open source, has a public issue tracker, etc. If there was an important *thing* in Docker called  "bootfs", we would find developers discussing it in related code changes, bug analysis, etc. If I was forced to make a guess, I'd agree it means the host filesystem, it's nothing like the suggestion in the question, and it's not really worth paying attention to.

Comment: I see your point. I recently tried to find out what election algorithm MongoDB uses, which as you may know is also open source. But they won't tell you in their documentation. Now some say it's Paxos, others say it's RAFT, some say it's something in between. Nobody really knows it, but it definitely exists. Kinda little different topic, though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find much info about the existence of bootfs in Docker either. However, I found discussion of the topic The Docker Book by James Turnbull:

> A Docker image is made up of filesystems layered over each other. At
> the base is a boot filesystem, bootfs, which resembles the typical
> Linux/Unix boot filesystem. A Docker user will probably never interact
> with the boot filesystem. Indeed, when a container has booted, it is
> moved into memory, and the boot filesystem is unmounted to free up the
> RAM used by the initrd disk image.
>
> So far this looks pretty much like a typical Linux virtualization
> stack. Indeed, Docker next layers a root filesystem, rootfs, on top of
> the boot filesystem. This rootfs can be one or more operating systems
> (e.g., a Debian or Ubuntu filesystem).

https://dockerbook.com/ Version: v18.09 (6172afc), p.72

Comment: I got here because of the book. Now I'm wondering if it's correct or not..